# Zend Framework and response gzip compression

Tags: zend-framework, gzip

I'm looking for a way to gzip my XML responses and only them. I didn't find any materials how to do this in Zend Framework. I have a response method in my abstract controller, like this:

```
public function xmlResponse(SimpleXMLElement $xml, $contentType = null){
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('noViewRenderer', true);

    $this->_response->setHeader('Content-Type', ($contentType) ? $contentType : 'text/xml');
    $this->_response->setBody($xml->asXML());
} // xmlResponse
```

and I want to add gzip compression in here.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
$this->_response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-gzip');
$filter     = new Zend_Filter_Compress('Gz');
$compressed = $filter->filter($xml->asXML());
$this->_response->setBody($compressed);
```

**EDIT**: You could try this, I have not tested it though:

```
$this->_response->setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");  
$this->_response->setHeader("X-Compression", "gzip");  
$this->_response->setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");  
$this->_response->setHeader("Content-type", "text/xml");  
$this->_response->setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
$filter = new Zend_Filter_Compress('Gz');
$compressed = $filter->filter($xml->asXML());
$this->_response->setBody($compressed);
$this->_response->sendResponse();
```

**EDIT**: Or you could just add this line to your .htaccess file

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
```

I hope this helps

Kind regards,

Garry

Comment: Not really. I want to do something like this:  $this->_response->setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate'); , but I receive xml parsing error.

Comment: Close, but as a result I get error "Content encoding error". Using gzencode instead of compress works fine but size of the response is the same as without gzip.

Comment: You could forget about encoding in ZF and simply add AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml to your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **nginx** server, just uncomment the following at your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Add **text/xml** is in it! That's my config.

```
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
```

Then restart it via `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`.